# how to create invoice detail with linq in crm

Tags: c#, linq, crm, invoice

I faced this error while creating an invoicedetail in visual studio using linq to crm.

The exception triggers with xrm.savechanges();

```
SaveChangesException was unhandled
An error occured while processing this request
```

This Is the code

```
 var units = 
(from unit in xrm.UoMSet where unit.Name == "one dollar" select unit).Single();
                  InvoiceDetail newinvprod = new InvoiceDetail();
                  var invoices = (from inv in xrm.InvoiceSet where inv.Name == Name1 select inv).Single();
                  newinvprod.invoice_details = invoices;
                  newinvprod.product_invoice_details = payments.new_product_new_payment;
                  newinvprod.unit_of_measurement_invoice_details = units;
                  newinvprod.Quantity = payments.new_product_new_payment.StandardCost;
                  xrm.AddObject(newinvprod);
                  xrm.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the inner exception? It will provide further detail.

Comment: Thanks James I already solved the problem, it was the parent Id I was forced to create an entityreference with Id of an invoice, then set it as parent Id fore the invoicedetail object